# Leaflet and Shiny R circles don't appear with map$addCircle when I change tile layers

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I have some code that allows me to change the tile layers using leaflet and shiny for R. When I try to add Circles using the leaflet `addCircle()` function the circles do not appear on the map that is output. There is no error given the circles simply not longer appear. I'd like to be able to add the same circles to all the tile layers as I modulate them.  I have attached the `ui` and `server` code.  Thank you very much for your help.

ui.R:

```
library(shiny);library(leaflet)
shinyUI(navbarPage("Switch Map",
   tabPanel("Map",
      div(class="outer",tags$head(includeCSS("styles.css")),
          htmlOutput("mapp",inline=TRUE)),
      absolutePanel(top = 60, left = "auto", right = 20, bottom = "auto",
          selectInput("mapPick", "Background Map",c("OpenStreetMap" = "http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
         "MapQuestOpen.Aerial"= "http://oatile3.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/sat/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg"),
         selected = c("http://oatile3.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/sat/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg"))))))

server.R:

library(shiny);library(leaflet)
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$map1 <- reactive(TRUE)
  map1 <- createLeafletMap(session, "map")
  output$mapp <- renderUI({
    input$mapPick
    isolate({
    leafletMap("map", "100%", "100%",
       initialTileLayer = input$mapPick,
       initialTileLayerAttribution = HTML('Fix This Later'),
       options=list(center = center(),zoom = zoom()))
    })
  })
  zoom <- reactive({
    ifelse(is.null(input$map_zoom),5,input$map_zoom)
  })
  center <- reactive({
    if(is.null(input$map_bounds)) {
      c(40, -98.85)
    } else {
      map_bounds <- input$map_bounds
      c((map_bounds$north + map_bounds$south)/2.0,(map_bounds$east + map_bounds$west)/2.0)
    }
  })


################  here is the snippet of code where I add the circles but doesn't yield ################  any circles
################  clinicDataReactive is some data I import.  I didn't include this part of ################  server for brevity

session$onFlushed(once=TRUE, function() {
  paintObs <- observe({
    sizeBy <- input$size
    clinicData<-clinicDataReactive()
    colorData<-clinicData$Facility.Type
    colors <- brewer.pal(3,"Set1")[cut(colorData, 3, labels = FALSE)]
    
    # Clear existing circles before drawing
    map$clearShapes()
    # Draw in batches of 1000; makes the app feel a bit more responsive
    chunksize <- 1000
    for (from in seq.int(1, nrow(clinicData), chunksize)) {
      to <- min(nrow(clinicData), from + chunksize)
      zipchunk <- clinicData[from:to,]
      # Bug in Shiny causes this to error out when user closes browser
      # before we get here
      try(
        map$addCircle(
          zipchunk$latitude, zipchunk$longitude,
          (zipchunk[[sizeBy]] / max(clinicData[[sizeBy]]))*5000,
          zipchunk$Index,
          list(stroke=FALSE, fill=TRUE, fillOpacity=0.4),
          list(color = colors[from:to])
        )
      )
    }
  })
  
  # TIL this is necessary in order to prevent the observer from
  # attempting to write to the websocket after the session is gone.
  session$onSessionEnded(paintObs$suspend)
})


})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shiny-independent solution using the `baseGroups` feature of `addLayersControl`

```
library(leaflet)
dat <- data.frame(lon = c(0, 0), lat = c(0, 1))
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles(urlTemplate = "http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", group = "OpenStreetMap") %>%
  addTiles(urlTemplate = "http://oatile3.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/sat/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg", group = "MapQuestOpen.Aerial") %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen, group = "Stamen") %>%
  addLayersControl(baseGroups = c("OpenStreetMap", "MapQuestOpen.Aerial", "Stamen"), options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)) %>%
  addCircles(data = dat, lat = ~lat, lng = ~lon, radius = 1e5)
```

However, the MapQuest tile server URL you've given  seems to have stopped working last year.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMxn1.png)